# Why does this code print addresses?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Why didn't I get a compile time error while accidentally printing only one dimension of a 2D array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i;
    int arr[2][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //<- Declared a 2D array

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);  // <- Accidently forgot a dimension
    }
}
```

I should have received a compile time error but instead I got a group of addresses! Why? What did `arr[0]` mean in this context to the compiler?

Comment: Because an *array* type (and this is what the type of `arr[i]`) is *decaying* to a pointer.

Comment: It should produce a warning (wrong format specifier `%d` for type `int*`) though, if enabled. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d995ce5a6a38cb2

Comment: Technically the output is undefined behaviour because `%d` cannot be used for pointers.

Comment: BTW: unrelated to your problem: `void main()` is wrong, it should be `int main()`.

Comment: why is void main() wrong ? Isn't it unnecessary effort to do the same thing with int main() and return?The code worked fine in Dev C++ IDE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An expression with *array type* evaluates to a **pointer to the first array element** in most contexts (a notable exception, among others, is the `sizeof` operator).

In your example, `arr[i]` **has** array type. So it evaluates to a pointer of type `int (*)[]` (a pointer to an array). That's what's getting printed. Printing a pointer with `%d` is **undefined behavior**, because `printf()` will read the pointer as if it was an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Felix Palmen's answer explains the observed behavior.

Regarding your second question: the reason why you don't get a warning is you did not ask for them.

Compilers are notoriously lenient by default and will accept broken code including obvious undefined behavior.  This particular one is not obvious because  `printf()` accepts any number of extra arguments after the initial format string.

You can instruct your compiler to emit many useful warnings to avoid silly mistakes and detect non obvious programming errors.

- `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`
- `clang -Weverything -Werror`
- option `/W3` or `/W4` with Microsoft Visual Studio.

`gcc` and `clang` will complain about the sloppy initializer for array `arr`. It should read:

```
int arr[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

The print loop is indeed surprising, did you really mean to print the array with a single loop?

Note also that the standard prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`.